# Restaurant with levitating booths

Tags: story-identification

There's a scene in a restaurant where the booths fly (antigravity).  When the restaurant first opened, the booths could be steered by their occupants; but drunks would pour food on other customers, so now the booths fly on programmed paths.

What's the story?  Could be by Larry Niven (in which case I most likely read it before 1981), or not.

Comment: I searched for `larry niven restaurant antigravity` and found ... [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven_(restaurant)).

Comment: I think this is my first question to be listed on Hot Questions, woohoo!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is **Handicap** (also known as [The Handicapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handicapped)), by Larry Niven

> Cziller's House of Irish Coffee. Inside, the place was still a cube, a
>   one-story building forty meters high. Padded horseshoe-shaped sofas
>   covered the entire floor, so close you could hardly squeeze between
>   them, each with a little disk of a table nestling in the center...
>
> "Interesting place," said Jilson. "These booths were built to float...
>   It didn't work out. Lovely idea though. The chairs would swoop through
>   the air, and if two people at two tables wanted to meet they'd slide
>   their booths together and lock them magnetically."

There's mention of the drunks and their game

> "It was fun. The guy who thought it up must have forgot that people
>   come to a  bar to get drunk. They'd crash the booths together like
>   bumper cars. They'd go  as high as they could and then pour out their
>   drinks. The people underneath  didn't like that, and maybe there'd be
>   a fight. I remember seeing a guy get  thrown out of a booth. He'd have
>   been dead if that tinsel centrepiece hadn't  caught him. I hear
>   another guy did die; he missed the branches."
>
> "So they grounded the booths."
>
> "No. First they tried to make the course automatic. But you could
>   still pour  drinks on the people below, and there was more skill in
>   it. It got to be a game.  Then one night some idiot figured out how to
>   short the autopilot, but he forgot  the manual controls had been
>   disconnected. His booth landed on another and  injured three important
>   people. Then they grounded the booths."

Comment: 4-second jinx. Looks like yours fits better though.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - A day late and a dollar short, as my dear granny would say

Comment: Your granny used *dollars*?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes, Canadian dollars, admittedly.

Comment: Ninja'd! This is definitely it. I took a detour through "worlds of known space" before looking into "neutron star"

Answer (score 3):

Could it be Larry Niven's short story ["Intent to Deceive", aka "The Deceivers"](http://news.larryniven.net/biblio/display.asp?key=25&order=4&direction=1)?

I can't find a full text online to check the details, but I did find a [summary](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2007/12/larry-niven-intent-to-deceive-robots-go.html):

> It's told as a frame story - by Lucas Garnet, 174 years old, to Lloyd Masney, half Lucas age. In a fully automated robots-where-you-expect-humans restaurant called Red Planet. Lucas, the narrator is uncomfortable in a no-humans restaurant, & tells a personal experience from "around 2025" with very early versions of such restaurants - that is the main story. Near end, Lucas tells us he had made up the main story. But made up or not, that is the main story.
>
> Lucas & a friend Dreamer Glass visited a then new all-automated restaurant called Herr Ober. "The only human beings involved were the maintenance crew, & they only showed up once a week. Everything else ... was machinery."

Larry Niven, check. Novel sci-fi restaurants, check. Can't be sure of the details though.

Comment: The full text is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v26n04_1968-04#page/n147/mode/2up). Doesn't seem to match.

Comment: There are no floating boots in "Intent to Deceive", just a fully robotic restaurant. And shrimp cocktails. Lots of shrimp cocktails.